# Question about an element at $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

Assume that $n,q>1$ and $n=\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}$.
How do I prove that $q\in \mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$?

$$\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}= \left\{a\mid1\le a<n;\  \gcd(a,n)=1 \right\}$$

Thank you!

Comment: You prove that $q<n$ and that ${\rm gcd}(q,n)=1$, which is not very hard!

Comment: How? I tried proof that $qx+ny=1$, but I didn't succeeded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}=1+q+q^2+\ldots +q^{r-1} = n$.

So $q < n$ and $n + q(-1-q-\ldots -q^{r-2}) = 1$.

So $\gcd(n,q) = 1$ and $q\in \mathbb Z^{*}_n$